# MultiValueDictKeyError while submitting Django form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and I am working on a site which should take user input and use it for further operations. I am using a simple text field and I am trying to access the input using request.POST method, however this is giving **MultiValueDictKeyError** on the name of the text field.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import openpyxl
import math    


def index(request):
        if "GET" == request.method:
            return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:
            excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
    
            # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
            # USING TEXT BOX
            sheet_id = request.POST["leadtime"]
            sheet_name = str(sheet_id) + "_Day_Lead"
            
            worksheet = wb["Observed"]
            worksheet1 = wb[sheet_name]
```

index.html

```
<div class="md:flex flex-col w-full items-center">
               <div class="relative mb-4">
                    <form action="index" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token%}
                    <label for="full-name" class="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-600">Duration of Lead Time in Day(s)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="full-name" placeholder="1 to 5 or ALL" name="leadtime" class="w-full bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-200 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out">
                    </form>
                </div>
    
                 <div class="relative mb-4">
    
                    <form action="index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file"
                               title="Upload excel file"
                               name="excel_file"
                               style="border: 3px solid green ; padding: 5px;"
                               required="required"> 
                  </div>
                
    
                  <button type = "submit" class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-green-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-green-600 rounded text-lg items-center">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sheet_id = request.POST.get("leadtime")
```

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Comment: It is raising KeyError

Comment: @JPCode7 can you please share the full error trace back

Comment: Hey c.grey, I hope you are able to access the full error trace back.